# Is it wise to specify a country name in brackets when referring to foreign city in an official document

Tags: formality, proper-nouns, letter-writing, geography

While writing a formal document in an English language, I would like to know whether it's wise to specify a country name in brackets when referring to foreign city in an official document. For example, the one could say:

- *Back in Barcelona (Spain)* we were responsible for the comprehensive management of the customer's property portfolio.

**or**

- *Back in Barcelona* we were responsible for the comprehensive management of the customer's property portfolio.

## Context

The document is drafted in the UK. There is no Barcelona in the UK so the brackets may be redundant. I wouldn't like to create the impression that I felt the need to specify the country name as I may think that the reader does not know where the Barcelona city is. On the other hand, there is a town called [Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris,_Texas) in Texas, so there is a significant difference between:

- Back in Paris (Texas) ...

**and**

- Back in Paris (France) ...

Comment: I fail to see how this question is on-topic, as it is not about English.

Comment: @JasperLoy It is not on topic because it is not about English. The OP would have the exact same question if they were writing in Russian or Hungarian. There is nothing about Russian or Hungarian that would automagically fix this issue, and there is nothing about English specifically that makes it arise.

Comment: "Wise" is a matter of circumstance and opinion; one audience may strongly prefer brevity and another clarity, but familiarity and context inform the assessment of either. *Paris, Texas* will rarely appear in the same contexts as *Paris, France*, and even among people in the Texas town, it is unlikely that a reference to the French city would ever be confused. But the same may not be true of *Hyderabad, Sindh* and *Hyderabad, Telangana*, or of the country *Georgia* and the U.S. state of *Georgia*.

Comment: @choster Thanks very much for your comments. It definitely makes sense, as a rule of thumb I would try to be specific with less common geographic names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We write

> Back in Paris, France, we have wine

in this case, using a comma to separate a city from its state and putting a comma after the state. See http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp for example.